# Extending the background of an image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background

[image]

Here's an original image I have above.

Below, I indicated with an orange rectangle the area I want to use.

[image]

Right now, I just used a grey rectangle, but it's not working out/doesn't look natural. How do I add background and achieve a natural looking result?

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop has something called "content aware", which tries to replace parts of an image by automatically matching the texture and color of the selections surroundings.

Steps to recreate your background:

1. Crop your image as desired.
2. Make a selection on the same layer as your image of the areas you need to fill (using the any of the available selection tools; Magic Wand Tool, Rectangular Selection Tool, etc.)
3. *Edit → Fill...* and select "Content-Aware" from the dropdown.

   [image]

   The results are pretty good, but can sometimes be a bit off — see the extra piece of head/hair in the bottom left corner:

   [image]

   I used the Clone Stamp Tool to patch that, just <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the area you want to clone (in this case an adjacent open area of grey), and paint over the head with a click or two with a large soft brush.

   Ta-da:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the background is not a single color. It gradates between a couple of shades of grey.

Matching those shades and gradients will be difficult. Alternately, you could try using a soft focus paintbrush or eraser tool to blend the edges of the photo to your background.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will make a complicated if i explain to do with photoshop, 
Instead that just go to http://www.toolpic.com 
Click open file > then Go to Edit > 
Then Go to Free transform. And now you can expand the pics till the selected area you want. And then crop it .

It quick and easy way to do. Hope it helps.